# My application file is auto aligning to left on desktop everytime I save it. Works fine on Windows XP

Tags: c++, file, windows-7, mfc

I have an MFC based application. I have dragged the file created from my application to say(bottom right) of the desktop, it could be any location on the desktop.

Now if I open up my file again and perform a save operation, it always gets auto aligned to left. My application's files could retain their position on Windows XP.It works all fine there. This issue is on Windows 7 and Windows 8.

On debugging my codebase, I found that the call made to ::MoveFile() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), is actually putting the file to left of desktop.

I couldn't get any thing much on this issue. It seems nobody else has faced this problem :(.

Any pointers in this direction - What could be wrong, or if such things needs a completely separate handling and if there is a standard way to do that would be of great help.

Also, MS Word, Wordpad, Notepad all works fine on my win 7 and win 8 machine in the mentioned scenario.

Comment: The cause for this is that the MoveFile() function is actually removing the existing file from the directory file system records but then adding it back as a new file, therefore causing all file orientiation/location information to be lost.  This does not happen in Word and Notepad because they are not moving the file, but rather just editing the existing file's data in place.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann Impressive - you were able to deduce the actual problem from a ridiculously vague description of a symptom.